# Where can I ask about finding a name for shop?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm looking for suggestions for a name for a new baby shop (with kids clothes and accessories).

What Stack Exchange site can I ask about this on?

Comment: Call it "How is Babby Formed" and rake in the meme dough.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That question doesn't fit anywhere on Stack Exchange. The question is too broad because there are too many answers possible, and primarily opinion-based because the answers would be opinions, no facts.

Comment: Well, there was [Startup Business](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business) site which was in Beta for some years but failed. This could have been on topic there.

Comment: :( damn it @ShadowWizard

Comment: Can see why it's disappointing, @Pathum but guess Stack Exchange is simply not meant for such questions.

Comment: Sadly I have to agree @ShadowWizard